# Calling a remote command via ssh, using Ruby, improved syntax?

Tags: ruby, ssh

Currently I'm calling a remote script using the backtick method, it works, but it feels wrong and nasty...

```
`ssh user@host $(echo "~/bin/command \\\"#{parameter}\\\"")`
```

Can someone give me a better way of expressing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make it a little pretty, if that is what you are after:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

home    = "/path/to/users/home/on/remote"
binary  = File.join(home, "bin", "command")
command = "#{binary} '#{parameter}'"
puts `ssh user@host #{command}`
```

Otherwise, you can use the [net-ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh) library, and do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require 'net/ssh'
Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "<your-password>") do
  home    = "/path/to/users/home/on/remote"
  binary  = File.join(home, "bin", "command")
  command = "#{binary} '#{parameter}'"
  output = ssh.exec!(command)
  puts output
end
```

There are, obviously, automated ways of capturing remote user's home directory path, but I skipped that part.

Comment: Looks nicer indeed, using `Net::SSH`, I was wondering why you broke up the backticks style, instead of using `system`? - By the way, why not use `~` on remote?

Comment: Reason for using explicit path over `~` is more based upon my personal convention. I prefer not to rely on automatic path detection, esp. if the server is windows based, and also, prefer to use absolute paths over relative ones. Moreover, `File.expand_path("~")` can not be used in this case, since it will expand to the local server's home instead of remote server's home.

Comment: thanks for the info, I assumed `File` would expand locally.  What's a good method for getting the remote home folder?

Answer (score 2):

Use [net-ssh](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh). It's just a wrapper.

```
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start('host', 'user', :password => "password") do |ssh|
  # capture all stderr and stdout output from a remote process
  output = ssh.exec!("~/bin/command '#{parameter}'")
end

puts output
```

Comment: @r3mus - suggesting to use net-ssh is hardly a comment. Although it's not a particularly verbose answer, it is an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @Slomojo heh, well, it only said "Use `net-ssh` It's just a wrapper." at the time.

Comment: Hi @r3mus I know, I read the history, that's the context of my comment. Granted, I would've had to go read the docs, but they were linked. Nothing wrong with the answer, at least it was correct / valid.